# How to specify kubeconfig file location when using fabric8io?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, fabric8

According to [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/05/20/getting-started-with-the-fabric8-kubernetes-java-client), I can specify system property *KUBECONFIG* to tell defaultKubernetesClient to use the specified kubeconfig file instead of the default `~/.kube/config`file.

What should I do that then I'm using fabric8io?

Tks in advance.

Comment: providing `KUBECONFIG` with new path to kubeconfig file should configure client. Are you facing problems with it?

Comment: Hi, could you please tell if you've managed to resolve your issue? Have you managed to solve it with the answer provided by Rohan Kumar?

Comment: @DawidKruk Yes, it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is a typo in the blogpost, If I look at Fabric8 code [Config.java](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Config.java#L113), property name is `kubeconfig` not `KUBECONFIG`.

I moved my `.kube/config` file to `/tmp/mykubeconfig` and then I tested with the following code on [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) and it seemed to be working okay

```java
System.setProperty("kubeconfig", "/tmp/mykubeconfig");
try (KubernetesClient kubernetesClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    kubernetesClient.pods().inAnyNamespace().list().getItems().stream()
            .map(Pod::getMetadata)
            .map(ObjectMeta::getName)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, do you know how to configure kubeconfig file location when using official io.kubernetes.client-java ?

Comment: I see this example on their repository : https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/examples-release-12/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/KubeConfigFileClientExample.java#L39

Comment: @theotheo: Are you moving to official client from fabric8 ?

Comment: Yes, part of the function has been rewritten by fabric8io

Comment: part of which function?

Comment: like creating job/delpoyment, and get job/deployment status, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by rewritten? Do you mean copy? Fabric8 Kubernetes Client is older than official Kubernetes Client. All resources *OperationsImpl classes converge back to [BaseOperation](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/dsl/base/BaseOperation.java)

Comment: In case if you're uncertain about the differences between two clients. I wrote a blogpost last year about Difference between Fabric8 and Official Client: https://itnext.io/difference-between-fabric8-and-official-kubernetes-java-client-3e0a994fd4af

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to load the config using the lesser known method `Config.fromKubeconfig(String)`. The string is the contents of the file so you'd need to load that via another method, for example `Files.readString(path)`

This might be preferable to tweaking changing system properties. In my situation I'm creating an application which connects to multiple clusters, and therefore needs to create multiple KubernetesClient instances each with separate kubeconfig files.

```
Config config = Config.fromKubeconfig(Files.readString(Path.of("/etc/my-special-config.yaml")));
KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().withConfig(config).build();
```