# how to deal with java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc when using fabric8io?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, fabric8

I was using fabric8io to write a service function, relevant code is as below

```
KubernetesClient fabricClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
fabricClient.pods().inNamespace("xxxnamespace").withLabel("somekey", somevalue).list().getItems()
```

It was working fine when I'm doing unit test.
But when I was deploying the whole application, and trigger the service funtion, it throws an error as below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing bean
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.MethodInvokingStateMachineRuntimeProcessor.process(MethodInvokingStateMachineRuntimeProcessor.java:70) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineHandler.handle(StateMachineHandler.java:135) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineHandlerCallHelper.getStateMachineHandlerResults(StateMachineHandlerCallHelper.java:438) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineHandlerCallHelper.callOnTransition(StateMachineHandlerCallHelper.java:237) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.StateMachineObjectSupport.notifyTransition(StateMachineObjectSupport.java:225) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractStateMachine$3.transit(AbstractStateMachine.java:329) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.handleTriggerTrans(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:287) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.handleTriggerTrans(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:210) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.processTriggerQueue(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:450) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.access$200(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:64) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor$1.run(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:330) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.scheduleEventQueueProcessing(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:353) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor.access$500(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:64) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor$2.triggered(DefaultStateMachineExecutor.java:540) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.trigger.CompositeTriggerListener.triggered(CompositeTriggerListener.java:34) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.trigger.TimerTrigger.notifyTriggered(TimerTrigger.java:123) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.trigger.TimerTrigger.access$000(TimerTrigger.java:33) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.trigger.TimerTrigger$1.run(TimerTrigger.java:117) [spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [biztech-bos]  failed.
    at com.xxxx.saveBuildLog(BosBuildLogAop.java:56) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.xxxx.BosBuildLogAop.logAround(BosBuildLogAop.java:39) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor689.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.xxxx.statemachine.TransitionActionConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$165e28b8.checkingIncrementDtsDeploy(<generated>) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor823.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:130) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:111) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:390) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:116) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:365) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.java:243) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.process(StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.java:119) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.MethodInvokingStateMachineRuntimeProcessor.process(MethodInvokingStateMachineRuntimeProcessor.java:68) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [list]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [null]  in namespace: [biztech-bos]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64) ~[kubernetes-client-5.2.1.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72) ~[kubernetes-client-5.2.1.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.listRequestHelper(BaseOperation.java:168) ~[kubernetes-client-5.2.1.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:664) ~[kubernetes-client-5.2.1.jar:?]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.list(BaseOperation.java:86) ~[kubernetes-client-5.2.1.jar:?]
    at com.xxxx.service.impl.DTSServiceImpl.checkDeployIncrementDts(DTSServiceImpl.java:217) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.xxxx.configuration.statemachine.TransitionActionConfig.checkingIncrementDtsDeploy(TransitionActionConfig.java:96) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.xxxx.configuration.statemachine.TransitionActionConfig$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f83ad12a.invoke(<generated>) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.xxxx.server.aop.BosBuildLogAop.saveBuildLog(BosBuildLogAop.java:52) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.xxxx.server.aop.BosBuildLogAop.logAround(BosBuildLogAop.java:39) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor689.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.xxxx.server.configuration.statemachine.TransitionActionConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$165e28b8.checkingIncrementDtsDeploy(<generated>) ~[bos-coordinator-server-1.30.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor823.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:130) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:111) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:390) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:116) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:365) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.support.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.java:243) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.process(StateMachineMethodInvokerHelper.java:119) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.statemachine.processor.MethodInvokingStateMachineRuntimeProcessor.process(MethodInvokingStateMachineRuntimeProcessor.java:68) ~[spring-statemachine-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
...
```

in which `DTSServiceImpl`is my service implementation class.
On the deployment machine, I was putting kubeconfig file on ~/.kube/config, and `kubectl`command line is woking fine. 
I have no clue how to handle this problem. Any idea how should I find out the exception reason？
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is this code running? As a Pod? Is it a server outside kubernetes cluster?

Comment: @Yayotrón It's a SpringBoot application, running in a virtual machine. The main function of this service is to create job/deployments and to detect the status of those jobs/deployments.

Comment: The question was where it is running, on which server? Inside kubernetes cluster or outside of it?

Comment: @Yayotrón it's running on a virtual machine, outside of the k8s cluster.

Comment: Looks like KubernetesClient is not able to find your `.kube/config` file.

Comment: @RohanKumar Yes, indeed! I was setting a wrong location path for some maven issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric8 uses Kubernetes REST API to perform their operations, by default their HTTP client is assuming that it's running inside kubernetes cluster which is why it's trying to reach `kubernetes.default.svc`

Since you're calling it outside the cluster then you must tell Fabric8 the address of your cluster, this can be done by specifying the host during creation of the client

```
new DefaultKubernetesClient("https://my-cluster");
```

If you're able to SSH to the server which is running your application and ping the cluster address, most likely fabric8 will work.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I was using new DefaultKubernetesClient() to get the client, since I was hoping it can read the kubeconfig file and get the cluster information. And I finally find out the problem: I was setting ```kubeconfig``` system property to kubeconfig file location, but the path is invalid, so fabric8 client didnt get the cluster information, as well as the authentication tokens. By setting it right, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yayotron and my colleagues, it turns out that I was setting the wrong path to `kubeconfig` system property.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586863/how-to-specify-kubeconfig-file-location-when-using-fabric8io), I was setting `kubeconfig` system property to some specific path, so that fabric8 client can get the kubeconfig file from that path and get clusters informations / authentication tokens, etc.
So if anyone meet this exception in the future, you can consider whether if the client configuration has been configured right.